# Eliminar el último carácter especial de las celdas en una columna (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Estaba haciendo una macro en Excel en la cual tengo una columna llamada "programas" y en sus celdas cada valor termina con un "*", por lo que necesito hacer una macro para automatizar ese proceso, hacer click en el botón y se borren automáticamente los asteriscos del final de todas las celdas de mi columna (entiendo que se puede hacer sin macro pero necesito el proceso en un boton)

Tengo este código que me aplica solo para la celda activa pero no supe replicarlo para una columna entera.

```
    Dim xlString As String
    Dim ultimo As String
    
    ultimo = Right$(xlString, 1)
    MsgBox ultimo
        
    ActiveCell = Replace(ActiveCell, "*", "")
```

Link Foto:

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que hacer un bucle desde la primera hasta la última fila.

Suponiendo que todos tus datos tengan un asterisco al final, entonces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes eliminar el asterisco con este código:

```
Sub limpiar()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim UltimaFila As Long

Set rng = Range("A1") 'cambia A1 por la primera celda de la columna

UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row

For i = rng.Row To UltimaFila Step 1
    Cells(i, rng.Column).Value = Left(Cells(i, rng.Column).Value, Len(Cells(i, rng.Column).Value) - 1)
Next i

Set rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Y te quedará algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Elier, no es necesario utilizar un bucle, un `rng.Replace...` te lo haría de una.